# How to reset datagridview having checkbox after filter is applied in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm new to c# coding and i'm struck with this.

I have a DataGridView with a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column, which is databound to a list.

After applying filter to datagridview,filter works fine,but if i check the row using checkbox,i can't retain it since on clicking on back i load datagridview once again which looses checkbox selection also CheckBoxColumn is created once again.

I need to retain checkbox selection with/without filter also checkboxcolumn should appear once when i reset datagridview

```
public AddressReport1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadData();//load gridview
    }
    public void loadData()
    {

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ContactId,ReceiverName,City,Address,ContactNo1,ContactNo2,GSTNumber,State FROM tbl_contacts", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSelect);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgvAddressReport1.DataSource = dt;
        //create checkbox column dynamically in datagridview
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn select = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

        select.Name = "select";
        select.HeaderText = "select";
        select.Width = 50;
        select.ReadOnly = false;
        select.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
        //add checkbox column in first row of gridview
        dgvAddressReport1.Columns.Insert(0, select);
        int dgvindex = dgvAddressReport1.Columns["select"].Index;
        MessageBox.Show(dgvindex.ToString());
        conn.Close();

    }
    private void btnBack_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         loadData();[enter image description here][1]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can create *DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn* outside of *loadData* method, Maybe in constructor. So it will be created only once.

To retain Checkbox selection, you can add boolean field in datatable or in database. Everytime you click on a row , just update that flag.

When you have *DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn* , when rebinding datasource, this column is automatically checked or unchecked according to boolean flag

Comment: Thanks for the assistance :) Can you please provide sample code for bool creation to update flag?

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAddressReport1.Rows)
            {
                bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["select"].Value);
                if (isSelected)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Value, row.Cells[2].Value, row.Cells[3].Value, row.Cells[4].Value, row.Cells[5].Value, row.Cells[6].Value, row.Cells[7].Value, row.Cells[8].Value);
                }
                
                
            }

Comment: Above code works fine to retain checkbox values,but on applying filter this is not retained

Comment: Checkbox values should be retained on paging also..pls help

Comment: Its not retained because you go to the database when applying filters.

Comment: You can add field in database , when you check in form, update that field. so , when you go to database on applying filter, just fill the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn using values from DB